# Does CFont::FromHandle(HFONT) assume ownership of the HFONT?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

`CFont::FromHandle(HFONT)` returns a `CFont*` that wraps the `HFONT`.  The [MFC documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfont-class?view=vs-2019#fromhandle) states that:

> If a `CFont` object is not already attached to the handle, a temporary `CFont` object is created and attached. This temporary `CFont` object is valid only until the next time the application has idle time in its event loop, at which time all temporary graphic objects are deleted. Another way of saying this is that the temporary object is valid only during the processing of one window message.

But it does not clarify if the temporary `CFont` object will call `DeleteObject()` on the `HFONT` when it is deleted.

**Does `CFont::FromHandle(HFONT)` assume ownership of the `HFONT`?**

**And if so, what happens if that `HFONT` is already wrapped by different `CFont` instance?**

---

In context: I'm working with legacy code that has a "font manager" object that I ask for the appropriate font. I know that internally the font manager stores the fonts as `CFont` instances, but its methods just hand them out as `HFONT`.

So I have code like this:

```
{
  CDC* pDC = GetDC();
  HFONT fontH = myFontManager->GetTheRightFont(state);
  CFont* newFont = CFont::FromHandle(fontH);
  CFont* oldFont = pDC->SelectObject(newFont);
  ..
  // draw some stuff
  ..
  pDC->SelectObject(oldFont);
  ReleaseDC(pDC);
}
```

My concern is that when the temporary `newFont` is deleted it will call `DeleteObject()` on `fontH` possibly leaving `myFontManager` with a `CFont` member instance that wraps a font handle that is no longer valid.

Note: I've read https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/535/Attaching-and-Detaching-Objects but I am no clearer how that applies to `FromHandle`.

Comment: For your second point, *is already wrapped by different CFont instance*; in that case, the 'different' instance (or a pointer to it) is returned, so no real issue. But your first (main) point is curious. When the temporary object is deleted, it's destructor will call DeleteObject. But, looking at the MFC source, it seems that there is some kind of internal 'handle map' used - but I can't say much more about that. Others here, I'm sure will know more.

Comment: To answer that you'd have to look at the implementation of `CGdiObject::FromHandle` (in *wingdi.cpp*) that ultimately calls into `CHandleMap::FromHandle` (*winhand.cpp*). MFC maintains a (per-thread) handle table to implement garbage collection of GDI resources. Garbage collection runs during idle processing (as the documentation hints) and if my memory doesn't fail is implemented in `DllCanUnloadNow`. I didn't fully understand the MFC source, but it does look like the GDI handle gets moved into the handle map (and is thus eligible for garbage collection). Though I could be wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable Excellent timing! You are one of the 'others here' I was thinking of.

Comment: @AdrianMole I wondered if that was the expected behaviour, but curiously the `CFont` returned by `FromAddress` seems to have a different address than the existing `CFont` that exists in `myFontManager`.

Comment: [Inside MFC: Handle Maps and Temporary Objects](https://www.mindfiresolutions.com/mindfire/Inside_MFC_Handle_Maps_and_Temporary_Objects.pdf) seems to explain most of the undocumented internals. Also a correction on my previous comment: MFC implements garbage collection to clean up its own temporary C++ objects (like the one potentially returned from `FromHandle`). It is opaque to me whether that ultimately takes down the GDI object as well.

Comment: FURTHER INFORMATION: it looks like my "font manager" code is using the WTL version of CFont, whilst the client code is using the MFC version. Aaargh! This may explain why `FromHandle` doesn't just give back the existing `CFont` instance for `fontH` as @AdrianMole suggested it should. Not sure where that leaves me, but thanks.